# Syntax Error. Maria DB. Al añadir una nueva columna a una tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, mariadb

Estoy intentando añadir una nueva columna a una tabla ya existente con datos, lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
ALTER TABLE NOMBRE_TABLA ADD COLUMN NOMBRE_NUEVA_COLUMNA VARCHAR  NULL;
```

El error que me indica es :

```
server> ALTER TABLE NOMBRE_TABLA ADD COLUMN NOMBRE_NUEVA_COLUMNA VARCHAR  NULL
[2021-04-06 17:59:45] [42000][1064] (conn=30115) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

El motor es **MariaDb**. He mirado en la documentación y es asi. Estoy intentando añadirlo a una tabla ya existente con datos, y que por defecto tenga null.

Comment: Y si lo que quieres es que el valor por defecto sea `NULL` deberías ponerlo así: `DEFAULT NULL`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la instrucción `ALTER TABLE` los tipos de columna se definen del mismo modo que se hace con [`CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

El [Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) dice que para `VARCHAR` y `CHAR` debes especificar la longitud:

> Los tipos `CHAR` y `VARCHAR` se declaran con una longitud que indica
> el número máximo de caracteres que desea almacenar. Por ejemplo, `CHAR (30)` puede contener hasta 30 caracteres.

Por tanto para declarar un `VARCHAR` debes indicar no sólo el tipo de dato de la columna, sino también el tamaño que quieres que tenga y si `NULL` debe ser el valor por defecto, conviene que lo indiques con `DEFAULT` (aunque también funciona de forma implícita).

Así tu código debería funcionar:

```
ALTER TABLE NOMBRE_TABLA 
    ADD COLUMN NOMBRE_NUEVA_COLUMNA VARCHAR(N) DEFAULT NULL;
```

**Considera cambiar `N` en la consulta por el tamaño que quieres para tu columna.**

Conviene saber también que si quieres agregar una columna después de otra, puedes hacer algo así:

```
ALTER TABLE NOMBRE_TABLA 
    ADD COLUMN NOMBRE_NUEVA_COLUMNA VARCHAR(N) DEFAULT NULL  
               AFTER UNACOLUMNA;
```

Aquí `NOMBRE_NUEVA_COLUMNA` se agregará después de `UNACOLUMNA`